# Codeigniter redirecting to another folder with the same name

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement [ajax-live-search](https://github.com/iranianpep/ajax-live-search) library in my Codeigniter project. The library is located in *application/third_party/jQueryLiveSearch/**core***.

This library has its own **core** folder.

The problem comes when I load the page, It looks like Codeigniter takes the default core folder from the framework, so instead of using `application/third_party/jQueryLiveSearch/core/jQueryLiveSearch.php`, Codeigniter tries to find it in `/core/jQueryLiveSearch.php`. This gives a 404 because that's not the right path.

It looks like Codeigniter's folders take priority.

What can I do? I cannot move the library to the Codeigniter's **core** folder. I also tried to make a route in `routes.php`. Is there anyway to tell Codeigniter to use an absolute path? Thank you.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cB1Ru.png)

Comment: What is the path to lib folder? Is it in the `application` folder?

Comment: show us your folder structuer.

Comment: @chalithageekiyanage No, I just noticed. We have the libraries outside. That might be the issue, I'll check it now.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam https://imgur.com/a/45zeUwd The problem might be the one that described chalitha.

Comment: can you show the script code using ajax.

Comment: @SandeepK.
https://codeshare.io/5X4dNk

Comment: it shows codeshare is over capacity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your libraries are outside the `application` folder you can access it with `baseurl`.

So the `absolute path` to your `library` is:

```
echo site_url("/lib/jQueryLiveSearch/core/jQueryLiveSearch.php");
```

In `AJAX Live Search` plugin you need to give the `url` in `jQuery Options`

```
jQuery(".mySearch").ajaxlivesearch({
loaded_at: <?php echo time(); ?>,
token: <?php echo "'" . $handler->getToken() . "'"; ?>,
max_input: <?php echo Config::getConfig('maxInputLength'); ?>,
url: <?php echo (APPPATH."/third_party/jQueryLiveSearch/core/AjaxProcessor.php"); ?>
onResultClick: function(e, data) {
    // get the index 1 (second column) value
    var selectedOne = jQuery(data.selected).find('td').eq('1').text();

    // set the input value
    jQuery('#ls_query').val(selectedOne);

    // hide the result
    jQuery("#ls_query").trigger('ajaxlivesearch:hide_result');
},
onResultEnter: function(e, data) {
    // do whatever you want
    // jQuery("#ls_query").trigger('ajaxlivesearch:search', {query: 'test'});
},
onAjaxComplete: function(e, data) {

}
});
```

Comment: The library is imported correctly, but when trying to make the AJAX request it makes the request to a wrong path. There isn't any url in the js code, so there's no way to change the request url from js. The error is still the same as described :(

Comment: I tried your code but it won't work. The closest answer I got was by using this:

url:  "../application/third_party/jQueryLiveSearch/core/AjaxProcessor.php"

but it says "forbidden 403". I tried it using APPPATH and base_url() but I'm still getting 403.

Comment: Did you try by turning off the `csrf_protection` in config file. `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;` ?

Comment: Yes, that parameter is set to false, but still giving 403. `$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;`

Comment: In `Ajax Live Search` plugin in github they have said to change the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in `core/AjaxProcessor.php` to your project URL.

`Change the URL for Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in core/AjaxProcessor.php to your project URL. Currently it is https://ajaxlivesearch.com.`

Comment: Did you try removing the `.htaccess` file in the `application` folder? As it block accessing the other files in application folder you will get a 403 error. So you need to remove it or modify the `.htaccess` file to allow access to your library.

Comment: Deleting .htaccess works! But there's a new problem:

`Error: Token mismatch. Refresh the page. It seems that your session is expired.` After trying to search something. It looks like the answer for this is here: [link](https://github.com/iranianpep/ajax-live-search/issues/86)

Comment: It is a `csrf` error.  Double check that you have turned off `csrf_protection` in config file. If you need to find the answer for the new error you will need to ask a new question.

Comment: @MikelGranero read the FAQ section in `Ajax Live Search` plugin in `github`. They have mentioned how to use it and turned off it. You can accept this answer if you find the answer for your first question.